# $(ab,ac)=a(b,c) , a >0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

$(a,b)$ denotes G.C.D of $a$ and $b$

Let $(b,c)=d$. So,  $d|b$ and $d|c$.

Claim : $(ab,ac)=ad$. As d|b and d|c , so $d|b.b...b$ ($a$ times) which means $d|ab$. similarly $d|ac$. So d is common divisor of $ab$ and $ac$.

Now let $f|ab$ and $f|ac$. To prove $f|d$

So we have $fq_1=ab$ and $fq_2=ac$. Also we have $dq_3=b$. So put in former equation i get $fq_1=adq_3$. Now $\frac{q_1}{q_3}$ may or maynot be an integer. How do i proceed ?

Comment: " so d|b.b...b (a times)" leave this out.  It's not relevent. $d|b$ and $b|ab$ so $d|ab$.

Comment: "Now let c|ab and c|ac. To prove c|d"  Use a different variable.  $c$ is already in use.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that $\gcd(a,b)=ax+by$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$? If yes, then use that to complete the proof.

Comment: how to prove that ax+by is lease positive element then?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(b,c)=d$. Now, we are to prove that $(ab,ac)=ad$. Assume the contrary, let $(ab,ac) = e$ where $e$ and $ad$ are distinct. Clearly, $ad$ divides $e$, hence $ad$ < $e$. Then, we have $(\frac{b}{d},\frac{c}{d}) = \frac{e}{ad}$. However, this shows  that $\frac{e}{ad}=1$ since $(b,c)=d$. Contradiction.

Hence, $(ab,ac)=a(b,c)$